# When corn starch is added to icing sugar, has it been cooked?

Tags: food-safety, safety, cornstarch, ingredients

My icing (powdered) sugar has 97% sugar and 3% "maize starch".

Answers to a recent question [accidentally ate raw corn starch](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/119790/20413) say that corn starch, like wheat flour, is meant to be cooked before eating, but icing sugar isn't usually heated. Does this mean the starch is pre-cooked (or otherwise processed to kill any bacteria) or that this isn't really a worry?

Comment: Sugar itself is good at inhibiting bacteria so it might be that the 97% sugar content plays a role here.

Comment: @dbmag9 I would expect packed corn starch to be dry enough to prevent bacterial *growth* but the answers at the linked question are more concerned with pre-existing contamination of the starch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's raw.

Raw cornstarch **generally shouldn't be eaten raw**, due to risks of causing digestive issues . But it's relatively **low-risk when consumed in micro-quantities**.

---

Here's a recipe on YouTube on how to make icing sugar, and it uses **1 cup of sugar** and **1 tsp of raw cornstarch**: [How To Make Icing Sugar At Home](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEl-oMj-hsQ)

Many other store-bought items also use cornstarch as an anti-caking agent, such as candies and shredded cheeses *(some brands, not all)*.

Comment: In a very brief Google search and Wikipedia, I have not been able to find an authoritative source that claims there is any danger from bacteria or other health issues.

Comment: In addition, the water activity in non-cooked applications of icing sugar is generally too low to support bacterial growth (though it won't kill some type of pathogens), so you tend to get less risk of a high inoculum and as a consequence lower chance of disease. Icing has about 0.78 and most bacteria need over 0.9 to grow according to [Bakerpedia](https://bakerpedia.com/processes/water-activity/)

Comment: @Rob Updated to reflect your comment; you're right, the sites that stated it weren't necessarily reputable.